# fixing input values and using them in the url of an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lowercase

I am trying to take a value from the input field and use it in the url of my ajax request. First, I want to fix to input to make it all lowercase so it matches the path of the file I'm requesting. For each of the two companies, I tried a different way of doing it, but neither seemed to work. Any ideas?

```
function requestCompany1 (evt) {
        var company1 = $('#companyInput1').val(
            function(i, val) {
               return val.toLowerCase();
      }).val();

console.log(company1);
        var url1 = 'assets/js/' + company1 + '.json'
        $.ajax({
            url : url1,
            dataType: 'json',
                data: company1,
            success: function(data) {
          //code the run on success
              }


function requestCompany2 (evt) {
    var company2 = $('#companyInput2').val().toLowerCase();
    var url2 = 'assets/js/' + company2 + '.json'

    console.log(company2);
    $.ajax({
        url : 'assets/js/spling.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: company2,
        success: function(data) {
                //code to be called on success
        });
}
```

I know I could combine the two functions to make it easier but I just wanted to lay it out first. Thanks

EDITED added`.val()` to the end of company1

Comment: Please define "neither seemed to work".

Comment: What is the response from the server?  Check Chrome's developer console->"Network"->"XHR" requests.  Also, I assume you are calling these functions somewhere? if not, put "()" after your last curly brace in that code snippet and see if company 2 works for you.

Comment: company1 was coming back undefined when i logged it

Comment: there is no response because it tries to used an undefined value in the file path

Answer (score 1):

First version should be logging the jQuery object for the input element to console since you have provided a function as argument to `val()` method... it is now a setter not a getter.

If you changed it to following it should return the value:

```
var company1 = $('#companyInput1').val(
        function(i, val) {
            return val.toLowerCase();
    }).val();
```

Second version  you aren't passing the url variable you created to ajax options object and there is a syntax error... missing closing brace for `success`

```
function requestCompany2 (evt) {
    var company2 = $('#companyInput2').val().toLowerCase();
    var url2 = 'assets/js/' + company2 + '.json'

    console.log(company2);
    $.ajax({
        url : url2,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: company2,
        success: function(data) {
                //code to be called on success
        }
   });
}
```

Sending `data` to a json file doesn't make much sense unless it is a dynamic file on server. If it is you would need to provide a key/value pair to pass as data

Comment: check out my edit above. company1 is coming back as undefined

Comment: is selector valid? code works in fiddle above. Try doing `alert( $('#companyInput1').length)` if it is zero selector isn't correct